# How to avoid persisting abstract data type objects as @Entity

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, abstract-data-type

In JPA with EclipseLink, I'm persisting data in a product database as follows:

```
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    CodeArticle ca = new CodeArticle(100);
    Monnaie m = new Monnaie(2.99);
    DescriptionProduit dp = new DescriptionProduit(ca, m, "Eau minérale");
    em.persist(ca);
    em.persist(m);
    em.persist(dp);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
```

As you can see, the `Monnaie` and `CodeArticle` classes are simple abstract data types (ADTs). It seems overkill to make them `@Entity` elements in JPA since they can simply be converted to primitive type (e.g., `CodeArticle` is an `int`, `Monnaie` is a `BigInteger` for precise calculations, but could be a float in the database). The reason I have the classes (and not primitives) is for encapsulation of validation logic, etc. Perhaps that is reason enough to persist them as `@Entity` elements? I'm not worried about invalid XML or invalid tables (if the object passes the validation in `new` I'm assuming it's valid).

Is there some simpler way to persist my `DescriptionProduit` objects that aggregate ADTs? I saw some examples of mapping conversions, serialization, etc., but I'm still relatively new to JPA. The closest thing to [mapping an ADT was with an Enum](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EnumToCode), but I couldn't see how to make it work for arbitrary ADTs.

Comment: Use a [Converter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Release/2.5/JPA21#A_Basic_annotation_example).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks! I tried to make the converters inner classes of the classes they convert (to maintain encapsulation) but EclipseLink was not able to instantiate them. I got it to work with them as separate classes, after making sure I added the converters (too) to the persistence.xml file.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do you mind to make your comment an answer so I can accept it? Or is there a better way for me not to have an unanswered question?